# how to time text appearence onclick using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, toggle, appearance

okay, this one is tough to explain
first of all here is my complete code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
#div{}
#eiv{}
#fiv{}
#giv{}
.main{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
}
.main .sec1{
width:50%;
height:50%;
top:0%;
left:0%;
position:absolute;
background: #0e83cd;
}
.main .sec2{
width:50%;
height:50%;
top:0%;
left:50%;
position:absolute;
background: #7abe93;
}
.main .sec3{
width:50%;
height:50%;
top:50%;
left:0%;
position:absolute;
background: #f06060;
}
.main .sec4{
width:50%;
height:50%;
top:50%;
left:50%;
position:absolute;
background: #ffa366;
}
.main .active1{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: #0e83cd;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
}
.main .active2{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: #7abe93;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
}
.main .active3{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f06060;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
}
.main .active4{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffa366;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
}
</style>
<script>
function myFunc1() {
    if(document.getElementById('div').className == 'sec1') {
        document.getElementById('div' ).className = 'active1';
        document.getElementById('div').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("div").className = 'sec1';
        document.getElementById('div').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    }
}
function myFunc2() {
    if(document.getElementById('eiv').className == 'sec2') {
        document.getElementById('eiv' ).className = 'active2';
        document.getElementById('eiv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("eiv").className = 'sec2';
        document.getElementById('eiv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    }
}
function myFunc3() {
    if(document.getElementById('fiv').className == 'sec3') {
        document.getElementById('fiv' ).className = 'active3';
        document.getElementById('fiv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("fiv").className = 'sec3';
        document.getElementById('fiv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    }
}
function myFunc4() {
    if(document.getElementById('giv').className == 'sec4') {
        document.getElementById('giv' ).className = 'active4';
        document.getElementById('giv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("giv").className = 'sec4';
        document.getElementById('giv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div id="div" class="sec1" onclick="myFunc1()">blah</div>
<div id="eiv" class="sec2" onclick="myFunc2()">blah</div>
<div id="fiv" class="sec3" onclick="myFunc3()">blah</div>
<div id="giv" class="sec4" onclick="myFunc4()">blah</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what i want to acheive is this - http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions/

i want the code to make a heading appear and onclick the heading dissapears and the content comes into display after a time (say 0.5 seconds) and when you close it(i want the closing to happen from the cross symbol, not the div as it does now) the content dissapears but the header comes after it has retracted(0.5 seconds)